# $f=g$ in $L^1$ confusion

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be in $L^1$. Suppose I am given
$$f=g\quad\text{as equality in $L^1$.}$$
Then $f-g = 0$, i.e. $\int |f(x)-g(x)| = 0$ so $f=g$ almost everywhere.

But $f=g$ also means $\int |f(x)| = \int |g(x)|$, then I cannot deduce that $f=g$ a.e. from this statement. So what am I doing wrong????

Comment: If you're given $f=g$ then why do you need to prove $f=g$...? Maybe you mean $\lVert f-g\rVert=0$.

Comment: Well I am trying to see what $f=g$ as an equality in Banach space $X$ means in this specific case $X=L^1$.

Comment: It's entirely possible that $\int | f(x) | = \int | g(x) | $ but $f \neq g$.

Comment: A implies B. A also happens to imply another statement C, but C (considered alone) does not in general imply B. There is no problem with this - nothing has changed the fact that A implies B.

Comment: @ZevChonoles But the problem is: A implies B and A is equivalent to C. But C does not imply B!!

Comment: @matt.x: "$f=g$ as an equality in $L^1$" and "$\int |f(x)| = \int |g(x)|$" are ***not*** equivalent statements.

Comment: Oh how stupid of me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equality in $L^1$ is NOT equivalent to having the same norm, which is what you'very written. It's like saying that two vectors are equal exactly when they hav he same length.